# Добавить элемент в начало словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Допустим у нас есть вот такой словарь:

`d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}`

Как нам добавить значение на **начало** словаря. Стандартное присваивание по типу `d['four'] = 4` - Добавит элемент в конец списка.

Comment: Только делать новый словарь, в который сначала поместить этот новый элемент, а потом остальные. У вас это учебные задания или что? Попробуйте уже сами решать.

Comment: Спасибо, нет, не учебные, просто столкнулся с проблемой, пробую разные решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать новый словарь, в который сначала поместить этот новый элемент, а потом остальные.

```py
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}

d1 = {'four':  4}
for k,v in d.items():
    d1[k] = v
print(d1)
```

Либо использовать `OrderedDict`, в нём можно двигать элементы:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
d1 = OrderedDict(d)
d1['four'] = 4
d1.move_to_end('four', last=False)
d1 = dict(d1)
print(d1)
```

Либо сделать из словаря список, тогда можно вставить элемент в любую позицию. А потом сделать обратно словарь:

```py
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
lst = list(d.items())
lst.insert(0, ('four', 4))
d1 = dict(lst)
print(d1)
```

Вывод везде будет одинаковый:

```
{'four': 4, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

если ключи уникальные, то такой код дает необходимый результат:

```
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
d1 = {'four':  4}

d, d1 = d1, d
d.update(d1)

d  # {'four': 4, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

существующие ключи `update` перезаписывает

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл как по мне самое оптимальное решение проблемы:

```
d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
new_dict = {"four": 4} | d
print(new_dict)

# {'four': 4, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

Новая фишка в python 3.9.5.